# Need to rename the files with have Date string prepended

Tags: powershell

I need to rename the files that are found with a pattern in a directory.
Date format with YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm-ss_ needs to be pref-end to the existing file name.

if filename `abc.bbc.ccc.txt` then it should be `YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm-ss_abc.bbc.ccc.txt`

actually files have to be moved to some other directory with new name.

Please provide me tips

1. how to rename the files as requested above in given directory.
2. moving the files with new name to any directory

i was trying this but not working

```
 $sysname=$env:COMPUTERNAME
 $Date = Get-Date
 $Now = Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss
 $host_date=$sysname +"_"+ $Now

 $file = "C:\Users\cherukpo\tracing\*\"   

 foreach ($file in gci $file -include *.etl -recurse)
 {       
      rename-item -path $file -newname ("$host_date_$_.name.txt") 
  };
```

Comment: Hello, haaaaave you met [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd772285.aspx)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is pretty basic PowerShell usage, to be honest - show that you've made an effort at solving the problem and ask for help with specific points where you're getting hung up.

Comment: $sysname=$env:COMPUTERNAME
$Date = Get-Date
$Now = Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss
$host_date=$sysname +"_"+ $Now

$file = "C:\Users\cherukpo\tracing\*\"   

foreach ($file in gci $file -include *.etl -recurse)
{       
    rename-item -path $file -newname ("$host_date_$_.name.txt") 
};

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change the names of the files in the original folder, just do this:

```
$date = get-date -format "yy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"
get-childitem | ? {$_.PSISNOTCONTAINER} |% {
    $name=$date + "_" + $_ 
    copy-item $_ "c:\path\to\new\folder\$name"
}
```

If you would like to rename the original files just do the same thing except with Rename-item before you copy-item